# What are the differences between shell script and in-shell execution that lead to this different if behavior?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

In xfce4-terminal I execute:

```
if [[ $(pgrep -x xfce4-terminal) ]]; then         echo "there are files" > test.txt;     else         echo "no files found" > test.txt;     fi
```

which writes `there are files` in `test.txt`. If I execute the same thing in a shell script, called while said xfce4-terminal is still open, it writes: `no files found` in the `test.txt`:

```
if [[ $(pgrep -x xfce4-terminal) ]]; then         echo "there are files" > test.txt;     else         echo "no files found" > test.txt;     fi
```

Why is that the case and what do I have to do to fix (make the shells script behave like the shell) this?

**Checking `$(pgrep -x xfce4-terminal)`**

From Terminal:

```
echo $(pgrep -x xfce4-terminal) > toast.txt
# 8257
```

From shell script:

```
echo $(pgrep -x xfce4-terminal) > toast.txt
# 8257
```

Comment: try putting [[ ]] in the shell script the way you did in the terminal

Comment: Try to write a shell script that just runs `pgrep -x xfce4-terminal`. Compare the output of that script to output of command `pgrep -x xfce4-terminal` run directly in a shell. See if there are any differences.

Comment: What shebang does your script have, and how exactly are you running it? If you are running it with `/bin/sh`, then `[[ ... ]]` will result in a syntax error - which will cause the `if` condition to fail regardless of the value of `$(pgrep -x xfce4-terminal)`

Comment: @steeldriver: I was using no shebang. I now use #!/bin/bash and it works. Thank you. Please make it an answer so I can accept it. Would be good if you can elaborate on why it does fail with /bin/sh (which might be the default if no shebang is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[[ ... ]]` extended test construct appeared first in `ksh` and was subsequently copied by other shells including `bash` and `zsh`.

If you try to use it in a simple POSIX shell `/bin/sh` (perhaps because you omitted the shebang for example - see [Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373223/which-shell-interpreter-runs-a-script-with-no-shebang)) it will result in a syntax error - and that will cause an `if` condition to fail regardless of the truthiness of the test. For example:

```
$ bash -c 'if [[ 1 -eq 1 ]]; then echo "equal"; else echo "not equal"; fi'
equal
```

but

```
$ sh -c 'if [[ 1 -eq 1 ]]; then echo "equal"; else echo "not equal"; fi'
sh: 1: [[: not found
not equal
```

**However**, `[[ $(pgrep -x xfce4-terminal) ]]` is not best practice for testing whether there is a running process named `xfce4-terminal`, even when the shell supports it. Instead of using a command substitution `$(...)` to capture the standard output of the `pgrep` command, and testing whether that's a non-empty string, you can use the *exit status* of `pgrep` directly. From `man pgrep`:

```
EXIT STATUS
       0      One  or  more  processes  matched  the  criteria.  For pkill the
              process must also have been successfully signalled.
       1      No processes matched or none of them could be signalled.
       2      Syntax error in the command line.
       3      Fatal error: out of memory etc.
```

So

```
if pgrep -x xfce4-terminal >/dev/null; then
  echo "there are files" > test.txt 
else  
  echo "no files found" > test.txt
fi
```

which will work in any Bourne-like shell (sh, ksh, bash, zsh).

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal version, you have `[[ ]]`, which evaluates its contents and returns an exit status of 0 if the contents are valid and 1 otherwise. If passed just a string, it returns 0 if the string has length > 0, and 1 otherwise. Since your command found something, it returns a string with length > 0, and the `[[ ]]` returns a status of 0, or 'true'.

`if` in shell scripts uses the return value of the `if` statement to determine whether to execute `then` or `else`. If the return value is 0, it executes `then`, otherwise it skips to `else`.

However, if you check `man pgrep`, it returns exit code 1 for "one or more processes matched the criteria." Therefore, `if` sees it as exiting with a nonzero error code, and skips to the `else`.

In order to fix this, just put `[[ ]]` in the shell script version as well.

Comment: In the second example; the command within `if` statement is not `pgrep`; its the **output** of `pgrep`. It most probably gives a syntax error, so non-zero return code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made a mistake while asking the question that made the question unclear. I have updated my question.

Comment: @raj I didn't have access to an Ubuntu install at the time, and Googled the man pages. I'm guessing the site I ended up at isn't very reliable, because it numbered error codes from 1 (which didn't make sense to me, because successful execution should be 0). I assume what you are describing is what is actually happening though.